# SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard step 3 of 10 fail

Tags: sharepoint-server

If anyone can help me ! I try to install SharePoint 2016 but when I use SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard my installation got a failure in the last step ( 3 of 10 tasks ). I tried a tons of possibility like cheking my rigths on my SP_Admin or restart the server, put a port for the SQL DataBase but nothing seems working. find bellow the errors contain in the log file generated automatically after the installation fail.

SINGLE SERVER SETUP

I do the installation on 
Windows Server 2012 R2

I ran the SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard and it started to execute. There was a brief pause on Step 3 of 10 - Configuration database creation. Then the wizard failed with the following message:

> An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown. Additional information about the exception: Failed to load one or more types. Please see the upgrade log for more details.

I analyzed the log file provided and found some error :

**SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard.  Version 16.0.4849.1000**

> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  11  ERR                                    Task configdb has failed with an unknown exception
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  11  ERR                                    Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Échec de chargement d'un ou plusieurs types. Veuillez consulter le journal de mise à niveau pour plus de détails.
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  11  ERR                                    Une exception de type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException a été générée. Informations complémentaires sur l'exception : Échec de chargement d'un ou plusieurs types. Veuillez consulter le journal de mise à niveau pour plus de détails.
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  11  ERR                                      Task configdb has failed
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  1  ERR                                            Task configdb has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                  Task base de données de configuration failed, so stopping execution of the engine
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                  Échec de connexion à la base de données de configuration.
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                  One or more configuration tasks has failed or some tasks were not run
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                One or more configuration tasks has failed to execute
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                  Échec de la configuration des produits SharePoint. La configuration doit être exécutée pour que les produits SharePoint fonctionnent correctement. Pour diagnostiquer le problème, consultez les informations détaillées sur l’erreur à l’emplacement C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_2_26_2020_12_35_56_773_833164061.log, corrigez le problème, puis exécutez à nouveau l’Assistant Configuration.

I found the following message too :

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Échec de chargement d'un ou plusieurs types. Veuillez consulter le journal de mise à niveau pour plus de détails.
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.LoadUpgradeActions()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_Actions()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_ActionsInternal()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.GetLatestTargetSchemaVersionBeforeMajorVersion(Type typeActionSequence, Int32 majorVer)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSiteSequence.get_PreviousTargetSchemaVersion()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateSequencesTable(StringBuilder sqlstr, Boolean siteSequence)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ConstructSiteNeedsUpgradeQuery(Guid siteId)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.GetSiteNeedsUpgrade(SPUpgradeSession session, SPContentDatabase database, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedUpgrade, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedFeatureUpgrade)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.AddNextLevelObjects()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, Boolean bRecursing, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.DetectLocalUpgradeStatus()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.DetectLocalProductVersions(SPProductVersions prodVer)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.UpdateProductInfoInDatabase(Guid serverGuid)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Join(Boolean skipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost, Nullable`1 serverRole)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Comment: That log file should tell you why it is stopping. Look for lines that contain ERROR (start from the end of the file and work backwards)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I've already checking it but I didnt find anything else for resolve my issue. If It's needed I can share all " ERR " in log file

Comment: That would probably be more helpful than a screenshot of a french error message... Try to pinpoint where it is failing and share the relevant lines from the log file.

Comment: It's done I updated it @RuneSperre

Comment: What about history? What did you do? You just tried to install SharePoint or install cumulative update? or what?

Comment: Did you read it? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e88947a6-7220-4cb0-a8c5-fccc42195b5c/config-wizzard-error-task-configdb-has-failed-with-an-unknown-exception-the-process-does-not?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: What I do is intalling SharePoint Server 2016. SharePoint Products Configuration Wizards fail after creating/installing the SQL things. @Raf

Comment: In the same folder there should be another file (that is refers to as the upgrade log). Seems like it could be some missing dependency, details are probably found in the upgrade log...

Comment: It is probably SQL permissions issue. Check that your SP_Admin has dbcreator rights.

Comment: Looks like not the same issue than me @Raf and the author resolving by restarting his server and mine got restarted many times before. I use a Administrator account for the DB. Rune Sperre are you talking about the file mentionned in the error ? I tried to check If there's any other file in the same floder but not sure If it's what you meaned.

Comment: I'll check my rights @Raf

Comment: I'm back @Raf dbcreator is enabled on my SP_Admin but it seem not working better I put every rights for seen If It will work with but nothing to do, I got the same error than before.

Comment: @RuneSperre In fact, I don't know If I am checking the right things because you asking to me to check the event log but what I put on this topic was the event log generated automatically by the configuration wizard. However, in event log windows I finded the error with " configuration wizard " but that's don't give me no more information about the issue that's why I need some help. I hope Moderator will reopened my subject.

Comment: did you run the prerequisite installer successfully?

Comment: If you're talking about the prerequisite installer for SharePoint, I did it successfully after I fixed the IIS problem. @RuneSperre

Comment: IIS problem? I don't think you have mentioned that. Like I commented on the other post, all details are needed. Not just bits and pieces... How was the SQL server set up? What windows version is that running on? etc...

Comment: @RuneSperre No, I didn't because my problem is caused with the Configuration Wizards of SharePoint and not with SharePoint prerequisite installer. I thought people already know this issues because I read It was a recurrent issue with SharePoint. The SQL server is make with SSMS. If you have reading everything you should know that the  version of windows is windows server 2012 R2. I added some additional information in my subject yesterday so the most important thing are on it.

Comment: Nowhere did you mention that this was a single server setup. I suggest you read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/install-sharepoint-server-2016-on-one-server and make sure all requirements are met.

Comment: Hello @RuneSperre all requirements are good. There's a DataBase created in Microsoft SQL server Management Studio called " SharePoint_Config" and " SharePoint_AdminContent_.... " but the SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard still had a pause on Step 3 of 10 - Configuration database creation. Then fail

Comment: did your prerequisites install ok? there are issues installing wcf dataservices 5.6 you have to use the offline installer from cmd.exe