# SharePoint Configuration Wizard step 3 out of 10 fail

Tags: sharepoint-server

If anyone can help me ! I try to install SharePoint 2016 but when I use SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard my installation got a failure in the last step ( 3 of 10 tasks ). I tried a tons of possibility like cheking my rigths on my SP_Admin or restart the server, put a port for the SQL DataBase but nothing seems working. find bellow the errors contain in the log file generated automatically after the installation fail.

I do the installation on 
Windows Server 2012 R2

I ran the SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard and it started to execute. There was a brief pause on Step 3 of 10 - Initializing the Upgrade Sequence. Then the wizard failed with the following message:

> An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown. Additional information about the exception: Failed to load one or more types. Please see the upgrade log for more details.

I analyzed the log file provided and found some error :

**SharePoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard.  Version 16.0.4849.1000**

> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  11  ERR                                    Task configdb has failed with an unknown exception
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  11  ERR                                    Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Échec de chargement d'un ou plusieurs types. Veuillez consulter le journal de mise à niveau pour plus de détails.
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  11  ERR                                    Une exception de type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException a été générée. Informations complémentaires sur l'exception : Échec de chargement d'un ou plusieurs types. Veuillez consulter le journal de mise à niveau pour plus de détails.
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  11  ERR                                      Task configdb has failed
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  1  ERR                                            Task configdb has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                  Task base de données de configuration failed, so stopping execution of the engine
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                  Échec de connexion à la base de données de configuration.
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                  One or more configuration tasks has failed or some tasks were not run
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                One or more configuration tasks has failed to execute
>
> 02/26/2020 12:41:27  8  ERR                                  Échec de la configuration des produits SharePoint. La configuration doit être exécutée pour que les produits SharePoint fonctionnent correctement. Pour diagnostiquer le problème, consultez les informations détaillées sur l’erreur à l’emplacement C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS\PSCDiagnostics_2_26_2020_12_35_56_773_833164061.log, corrigez le problème, puis exécutez à nouveau l’Assistant Configuration.

I found the following message too :

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Échec de chargement d'un ou plusieurs types. Veuillez consulter le journal de mise à niveau pour plus de détails.
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.LoadUpgradeActions()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_Actions()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.get_ActionsInternal()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.GetLatestTargetSchemaVersionBeforeMajorVersion(Type typeActionSequence, Int32 majorVer)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSiteSequence.get_PreviousTargetSchemaVersion()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.PopulateSequencesTable(StringBuilder sqlstr, Boolean siteSequence)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ConstructSiteNeedsUpgradeQuery(Guid siteId)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.GetSiteNeedsUpgrade(SPUpgradeSession session, SPContentDatabase database, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedUpgrade, Dictionary`2& dictSitesNeedFeatureUpgrade)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.AddNextLevelObjects()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, Boolean bRecursing, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPHierarchyManager.Grow(SPTree`1 root, SPDelegateManager delegateManager)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.ReflexiveNeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgrade(Object o, Boolean bRecurse)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.DetectLocalUpgradeStatus()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.DetectLocalProductVersions(SPProductVersions prodVer)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServerProductInfo.UpdateProductInfoInDatabase(Guid serverGuid)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Join(Boolean skipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost, Nullable`1 serverRole)
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
>      à Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard step 3 of 10 fail](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276786/sharepoint-products-configuration-wizard-step-3-of-10-fail)

Comment: No, there's actually no solution. That's why I request your help. I reading alot of subject on similar issues but no ones fixed mine. @RuneSperre

Comment: I flagged it as a duplicate as it is the same question that you reopened. To be able to help you, provide as many details as possible. Check your log folder and the event log, there should be a clear message as to what prerequisite is missing (the message "Failed to load one or more types."). Did you run the prerequisite installer? Did it complete successfully?